# How to create in View new row after each next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is here some way how to create new row after each row in View ?
Row should have same count of columns and their names and I would like to use conditions to fill them.

Example:

```
row A : 120 2122 bike 20130203 --- row from table from dbs
row B : 120 4444 012 0 ---new row
```

Is it possible?(by procedure or somehow else?)

Comment: Sql-server or MySQL? Also what would your criteria be to populate the new row?

Comment: This link is couse of more people should see this ask :)
But its MSSQL :), and row should be filled based on my different criteria. If its possible I would like to use case when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a cross join to a table with two rows:

```
SELECT 
...
   CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN col ELSE your calculation END
FROM table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS x) dt
```